# didDiscoverPeripheral is not called after upgrading from iOS 7 to iOS 8

Tags: core-bluetooth

I am calling scanForPeripheralsWithServices from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions callback of AppDelegate. The code looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    cm = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    [cm scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                               options:nil];
}

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager*)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary*)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber*)RSSI{

   NSLog(@"Did discover peripheral %@", peripheral.name);

   [cm stopScan];
}
```

Before upgrading to iOS 8 everything was working well, however after the upgrade (exactly the same code, no single line was changed) I am not getting any error, but also didDiscoverPeripheral is not being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appears that the major change which has occurred with Core Bluetooth in iOS 8 is that the BLE stack isn't powered on until you try to connect (or possible issue some other command).

```
CBCentralManager *cbCentralManager;
[cbCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:...];
```

This call used to issue a warning visible in the Xcode debug log saying that the central manager needed to be powered-up before it could be used. However, this warning was always a catch-22 — the only way to power-on the central manager was to send it a message, and the only way for it to process a message was for it to be powered-on.

Apple seems to have resolved this problem by handling power-on a bit differently. Now, after issuing the above command the central manager tells its delegate that its state changed via `centralManagerDidUpdateState:`.

We resolved the problem you describe by responding to `centralManagerDidUpdateState:` by re-issuing the `scanForPeripherals...` message.

Comment: I also looked for a solution to this problem! Thanks a lot it was working perfectly! I checked if the central.state is PoweredOn and then started scanning there. I removed the first scanForPeripherals...